# Fedora 25: switch between onboard graphics card and Geforce210

Tags: graphics, fedora-25

I have a Dell PowerEdge T430 running Fedora 25. It comes per default only with onboard graphics (which allows only a resolution of 1024x768 (at least I was not able to get any drivers running) and is insufficient for some applications that produce graphical output).

I bought a Geforce210 graphics card and plugged it in but how do I tell Fedora to use it instead of the onboard graphics?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to do this in the system's own System Setup ("BIOS configuration") — go to the Integrated Devices section and switch `Embedded Video Controller` to `Disabled`. I don't think there is any support for multiple video controllers to be active at the same time.